# Basics of designing a lightsail?

Tags: science-based, technology, space-travel

We all know (or know how to find) the “rocket equation” that drives the design of a conventional rocket, and we’ve gone over such things as “specific impulse” and the difference between fuel and reaction mass for more advanced rockets. There are books and blogs about it.

But what about photon sails?

How big does a sail need to be? I mean, what factors drive figuring out the particulars of a design?  How tight can an interstellar laser be kept, and how much power can you give it? Does it make a difference what wavelength is used?  How light-weight can a sail be?

**What are the absolute basics, and what resources are available?**

Comment: Sadly, this is probably going to be closed as "too broad". The best resource to answer questions about laser driven lightsails is here: http://www.lunarsail.com/LightSail/rit-1.pdf

Comment: I believe there was a theory about using the solar winds to power the sails. Of course, you'd have to wait on some proper gusts, and it's only one-way travel, but it sounded plausible to my amateur ears.

Comment: @Fayth85 solar wind does not exist beyond the [heliosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere), some 100 AU out. What I'm asking about are driven by **light**.

Comment: @a4android I wrote **light sail**, not solar sail, on purpose.  I'm interested in using lasers, not only ambient sunlight.  Also the Planetary Foundation’s [project is called *lightsail*](http://sail.planetary.org) so that seems to be the scientific term that is preferred.

Comment: Sorry, was that edit by @MichaelKjörling, not a4?

Comment: IMO, a *light* sail is not the same thing as a *lightsail* or even *light-sail*. (Remember, "light" can mean either "little weight" or "EM emissions in a particular part of the spectrum, as perceived by optical receptors".) Curiously, [space.se] has tags for both `solar-sail` and `light-sail`, but `solar-sail` is used far more (26 questions versus 2, with no overlap).

Comment: And tge SX tags distinguish their usage: solar-sail for the *sun*, light-sail «Questions about spacecraft propelled by the reflection of light, either from the Sun, **or an artificial source.**» , and why they are not alised  but distinct tags.   Point taken on the ambiguity of the word *light*.

Answer (score 3):

A solar sail works by using the pressure of focused light to propel a spacecraft forward. Note that this light would either have to be provided by a nearby planet or star - you can't put a fan on a sailboat in irons and expect it to move.

The ideal solar sail is made of a lightweight material that can span a large area (more surface area means more photon collisions), but it must also withstand impacts from cosmic particles as the ship travels. A material like carbon fiber comes to mind.

How does a solar sail work?

Einstein's equations say that the momentum of a photon, $p$ is: $p = \frac{E}{c}$ - where $E$ is energy and $c$ is the speed of light in a vacuum. By some simple rearrangement of the equation for photon energy, $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$, where $h$ is Plank's constant. Therefore, **smaller wavelengths** of light will have **more energy** and thus **more momentum**.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Solar_radiation_pressure) puts it, "An ideal sail is flat and has 100% specular reflection. An actual sail will have an overall efficiency of about 90%, about $8.17 \frac{μN}{m^2}$, due to curvature (billow), wrinkles, absorbance, re-radiation from front and back, non-specular effects, and other factors."

So now you might be saying, how big does my solar sail have to be? Well first, you're in space, so you don't really have to worry about friction. The solar wind will give you a decreasing acceleration as you go away from the sun or whatever light source you are using. Sailors on Earth use a method called "tacking" to move in a direction against the wind. However, tacking relies on the fact that the friction and hydrodynamics of the water and ship allow it to move in the forward-backward directions much more easily than side-to-side. In space, there is no real friction against your ship, so this maneuver would be much more difficult, [if not impossible](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/370/can-you-tack-against-the-sun-using-a-solar-sail).

Anyway, back to size. Because you're in space, as long as you have some initial acceleration, you will theoretically keep moving forever, until you are pulled into the orbit of some large space object. I don't know how much your spacecraft weighs, but I'll do some math with the ISS for this example, which has a mass of 419,600 kg.

At an initial acceleration of $8.17 \frac{μN}{m^2}$, we want to find out the optimal sail size for (I'm guessing interstellar) travel. A good benchmark is say, $0.90c$, or 90% the speed of light. The speed of light is $299,792,458 \frac{m}{s}$, so 90% of that is $269,813,212.2 \frac{m}{s}$ (we'll round to 2.7E8 m/s). We want to reach this speed in a reasonable amount of time, say a day. That's $86,400$ seconds (if we are on Earth days). So now we can pull up a kinematic equation and figure out our sail area. Newtons are just $\frac{kg}{m/{s^2}}$, so:

$2.7*10^{8} \frac{m}{s} = area * (419,600kg / 8.17*10^{-6} \frac{kg}{m/{s^2}}) * 86,400^{2}s$

This gives us an area of: $39,244,411.97 m^{2}$ or about 429,182 (square) football fields.

That's not good for us, but fear not, we can focus light energy in the form of lasers.

The pressure given off by light (reflection only) is $P_{pressure} = \frac{2E_{f}}{c}*cos^2(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between the light and the surface normal, which we'll round to $0$ radians because it's easy to calculate. $E_{f}$ is the energy flux of the light, which is the *rate of transmission per unit area*, or $\frac{W}{m^2}. The pressure term turns out to have units of N/m^2, since you can convert watts to Joules/second but that's another story. What we care about is seeing the amount of watts of power we need to provide this sail:

This time, we'll solve for a more reasonable sail size, say 1 square kilometer. This may seem big, but trust me, it's about to seem very unrealistic.

$2.7*10^{8} \frac{m}{s} = 1,000 m^{2} * (\frac{419,600kg}{P_{pressure}}) * 86,400^{2}s$

From this, we see that the pressure required is $11,601,100,800 \frac{N}{m^{2}}$. We can use our new equation to approximate the power of the laser required for this kind of travel. Note that we are just glossing over all the losses that take place between the power generator and the light hitting the sail, but those exist too, and are also dependent on distance - more on that later.

$\frac{1}{2}*c*P_{pressure} = \frac{W}{m^{2}} = 1.74016512 x 10^{18} \frac{W}{m^{2}}$

You might be asking yourself how big is that number, really? To give a helpful size comparison, I looked at http://www.climatecentral.org/blogs/helpful-energy-comparisons-anyone, which said:

> Terawatts (TW) are millions of megawatts, and this is a helpful unit when you’re talking about the rate at which humans are using energy worldwide. In 2008, for example, humans used energy (this includes all types of energy, not just electricity) at an average rate of about 16.5 TW of power — the U.S. consumed about one fifth of that, at 3.3 TW.

Our solar sail requires $1,740,165.12 TW$ of power, or about $105,465$ times the total energy consumed by the world in 2008.

Before I go farther, I apologize if any of my calculations are incorrect. I'm doing some quick napkin math here so I could easily be off by a lot, so please correct me if you notice something.

Still, it holds that solar sails require huge amounts of power to operate at, or they require very large sails. As for how tight an interstellar laser can be kept, that depends on where it's coming from. A laser originating on Earth will have to pass through our atmosphere - not efficient. Optimally, a laser would be generated in some kind of orbit where it could maintain direct contact with the craft.

How tight it can be kept really depends on how long you want to accelerate for. Since you are in space, once you achieve your optimal travel speed, you no longer need to step on the gas. In my calculations, I set travel speed at $.9c$ and our time to get to that speed at one day, but you could achieve the same speed at **much** lower energy costs if you took more time to accelerate to it, say a month.

Finally, the weight of a solar sail would have to factor into these calculations, but as I said before, you could make a solar sail out of a very lightweight material such as carbon fiber, which would greatly reduce the impact of this weight on transportation cost. Realistically, a method for creating large areas of solar sail cloth hasn't been engineered yet, so I can't give you a real estimate on how light your sail could be.

Those are the absolute basics, plus some more advanced knowledge. For anything else, the Wikipedia page on solar sail is very informative on the history of the subject and future projections.

I hope I've answered your question.

Edit:

Once you get to your destination, you need to be able to [slow down](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/can-a-solar-sail-reduce-the-speed-from-1-10-light-speed-to-achieve-a-solar-orbi). In the 1970s, [Robert Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward), an American physicist/sci-fi writer, [proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocheworld) [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Interstellar_flight) of interstellar flight using solar sails. [One method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starwisp) even involved using microwave beams to propel an unmanned spacecraft to an acceleration of nearly $24\frac{m}{s^{2}}$.

However, there are many problems associated with these high acceleration/high speed trips. For one, any acceleration over $25G$s ($245.16\frac{m}{s^{2}}$) will result in death or serious injury. Additionally, at even 20% the speed of light, interstellar hydrogen becomes a significant radiation hazard, along with causing [other problems](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/durability-of-solar-sails-how-big-of-a-problem-is-high-energy-proton-flux) for your sail.

I have also found a quick [calculator](http://www.georgedishman.f2s.com/solar/Calculator.html) that you can use to simplify solar sail calculations. However, it doesn't give an option of using an external source of light aside from the sun. However, [one of the links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocheworld) to Robert Forward's methods above gives a good approximation for the size and energy constraints of a craft accelerating over multiple years using lasers.

A good resource on the physics and material science of the sail itself is: http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/333Christensen.pdf. The NIAC is the NASA Institute for Advanced Concepts and is a reliable resource. The paper talks about the material stresses and manufacturing concerns that might arise in the large-scale production of a solar sail.

Comment: You ought to incorporate the power version of p = E./c, which gives a force of 300 MW per newton. For a mirror it's half this. So a nice starting point is that it takes 1.5GW to produce 1 g on 1 kg.

Comment: Nice observation, thank you @WhatRoughBeast !

Comment: I was supposing to accelerate via laser for *years*.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast you ought to post an answer.  *half* for a mirror? I thought a mirror would be double the momentum change compared to just emitting or just absorbing.

Comment: @JDługosz in that case, you can substitute my 86,400 seconds in with the amount of seconds in a year or two (make sure you square it). It will take quite a lot less energy - a much more attainable amount. The Wikipedia page says it's more in the range of gigawatt lasers. As for the distance they would be able to go, a high powered laser will probably travel far enough for your immediate purposes. However, when you do get to your destination, deceleration might be a problem, as lasers might not make it farther than necessary for the acceleration.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I would think the mirror would have the same force by power/newton as another surface. Could you elaborate on how you got the "half" figure?

Comment: I noticed you're new here and presumably to StackOverflow in general (or you’d have the association bonus).  It is much more *literary* than common discussion forums. Think more like Wikipedia articles: we edit each other’s posts, too.  I use the full site (not mobile app) on a tablet; just wish I could make the edit box bigger.  Anyway, I think you’re off to a good start and want to encourage you to keep posting. Feel free to try the chat room too.

Comment: @JDługosz - Because the mirror reflects light, there is twice the force exerted than if it simply absorbed it. Think of light as little balls (photons). if one hits the mirror and sticks, you get the momentum transfer p. But then the mirror has to "emit" the photon back the way it came, and this transfers another bit of momentum p. Total transfer is 2p, so it only takes half the power to exert the same amount of force.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I understand that, which is why I questioned your statement that the mirror **produces half the force.**  So it's a pronoun antecedent issue, not a physics issue.

Comment: What you are saying about the maneuverability of a solar sail isn't quite right. A solar sail is pushed not just in the direction that light impacts it, but also in the direction the light is reflected. That means by angling the sail with respect to the light source you can create lateral movement. Since the solar sail is in orbit this lateral movement can be used to increase or decrease the orbital velocity and therefore move the ship further from or closer to the light source.

Comment: You know that accelerating to 0.9C in a day is going to put your craft under a whopping 320G, right? That's not just out of scale - That's completely insane.

Comment: @JDługosz - Well, you're right in the sense that I was unclear. However, the 1.5 GW/g should have made it clear I was talking about halving the power required.

Comment: @UIDAlexD I think you dropped a decimal. I get 3200 gs.

Comment: And, since the craft will be 84 x 10^9 km away at the end of boost, this implies that, for a sail diameter of 1 km, the laser aperture will need to be about 5,000 km across. Anything smaller and the beam is diffraction limited to more than 1km, and the acceleration drops. Oh yes, and pointing accuracy of the beam must be well under 1 picoradians.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Either way, that number is only helpful if you want your astronauts to be red paste on a bulkhead.

Comment: Also, even at 99.99% Thermal effeciency you're still going to be dumping 10^14 watts of heat into every square meter of your sail. That kind of thermal flux is a great way to vaporize everything you hold dear.

Comment: Well, if we're being realistic, traveling at .9c won't be that fun either. It seems that the only physically possible way is to have low energy pulses over a very long time. Back to maneuverability though, how do you angle the sail with respect to a light source ahead of you to reflect light in such a way that you travel towards that source? Tacking works because there is some friction between the boat and water and you can catch wind inside the sail to push your boat in orthogonal tacks, but in space I don't see how that would work.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I’d like to see information on beam size limits in an answer.  Trade laser aperture (or down-stream fresnel lens) size for vehicle size?  In Forward’s novel they doubled the frequency instead of completing the zone plate for the deceleration stage.

Comment: @JDługosz do you mean the actual radius of the beam or the distance you can focus a beam in space?

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman both: how tight can the beam be kept across interstellar distances; what can be changed at the emitter to control this?

Comment: @JDługosz I'll edit my answer, I think I have some resources on this.

Comment: @JDługosz scratch that, I've got nothing really substantial to add. I was thinking Bessel waves might work in this situation to get around the diffraction problem, but that usually only applies to things like optical tweezing. You might try looking into the "Rayleigh length" - the distance it takes to double the cross-section of the light beam. So I guess the effective distance really depends on how big your target is and how big the emitter is. Therefore, it might work better to have multiple smaller emitters rather than one large one.

Answer (score 1):

Seek and ye shall find. There are, of course, resources such as the following books: --

*Solar Sails*: A Novel Approach to Interplanetary Travel, Gregory Matloff, Les Johnson and Dr. Giovanni Vulpetti, Springer/Praxis Books, 2008.

*Starsailing*: solar sails and interstellar travel, Louis Friedman. John Wiley & Sons, 1988.

*The Starflight Handbook*: A Pioneer's Guide To Interstellar Travel", Gregory Matloff, Dr. Eugene Mallove, Wiley Science Editions, 1989.
There are chapters on beamed-power and solar-sail spacecraft.

*Centauri Dreams*: Imagining and Planning Interstellar Exploration, Paul Gilster. Copernicus Books, 2004.
Like Matloff and Mallove (1989) above, this work has chapters on beamed-power and solar-sail spacecraft.

Websites with articles on the solar sail technology:

http://gregmatloff.com/solar_sails.html
 This webpage has the text of several articles by Gregory Matloff about solar-sails.

http://www.masteringphysicssolutions.net/mastering-physics-solutions-solar-sail/

http://www.physicspages.com/2015/05/14/solar-sails/

The two webpages above have the basic details supported by calculation for solar-sails.

www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet108/chapter6_bul108.pdf

The ESA Bulletin article details various solar-sail missions.

Proceedings of the Second International Symposium on Solar Sailing

www.citytech.cuny.edu/isss2010/ISSS2010Proceedingsvx.pdf

The Proceedings are a gold mine of papers on solar-sails and lightsails. No other way of summarizing its contents.

On a related space technology dusty plasma sail vehicles.

http://spacescience.msfc.nasa.gov/colloquium/archives/2003/summer/robert.html

This presentation outlines an alternative sail technology, while similar to magnetic sails, it utilizes a plasma confined inside an artificial magnetosphere laced with very small particles of dust and interacts with the plasma of the solar wind instead of solar radiation. The proposal suggests this would be comparable to conventional solar-sails, possibly better.

Comment: While it's important to cite your sources, it's discouraged to _only_ link to outside materials without giving a proper answer as well: "Provide context for links -- Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." [From the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I don't want to delete this/convert to comment as the links look useful and relevant but without a bit more context for each one it's pretty borderline, the fact that you have names and authors makes the list useful even if the links die so I've decided to leave it but it would be good if you could restructure the answer to be less "link only".

Comment: The question asked for resources for further study, so books and article pointers are welcome.  Detail need be only what the book is *about*, not a summary of the conclusions. For a title like “Proceedings…” I think the title says it all.  I just hope that the curated list is *useful* and not just a Google results list, and websites give details asked for and not just “hey, light sails are a thing.”

Comment: I am aware that links are discouraged, because the question asked for resources. However, The Starflight Handbook has chapters on both beam-powered & solar-sail vehicles. My copy of Friedman isn't at hand,so I can't check that. When time permits, I will edit the answer for more detail.